# Add "well-formatted" Assembly Reference with Roslyn

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, roslyn

In nutshell, I've been working on a tool which modifies all classes inside a solution with the .NET Compiler Platform. In order to do that, I have to add an assembly reference to all the projects.

Currently, I use this line of code:

```
var addedRef= MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(@"d:\Stuff\MyAssembly.dll")
                        .WithProperties(new MetadataReferenceProperties(MetadataImageKind.Assembly));

var sol = newSolution.AddMetadataReference(projectId, addedRef);
```

But unfortunately, it generates the following entry in the .csproj file:

```
<Reference Include="..\Stuff\MyAssembly.dll" />
```

Instead of that, I'd like to see this in my .csproj:

```
<Reference Include="MyAssembly.dll" />
```

Of course there is a nasty workaround: parse the .csproj files as xml and insert manually... but I really want to avoid this one since there is the .NET Compiler Platform.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The Roslyn stuff is fairly unconcerned about MSBuild representations -- it doesn't attempt to be the system to do that. You're best off just using XML or the MSBuild APIs or something else.

Comment: I just found this issue on the Roslyn's GitHub page:

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/5959

Anyway, thanks for your answer. I will do the XML-way workaround.

This will be fixed in the future.